# Mapbox do not hide markers on specific Zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Map with a lot of markers, normally mapbox automatically hides some markers at a specific zoom level. Is it possible to disable that feature so all markers would be visible all the time?

Ill add a layer with:

```
                map.addLayer({
                    id: "regulators",
                    type: "symbol",
                    source: "regulators",
                    layout: {
                        "icon-image": "triangle-15",
                        "text-field": "{title}",
                        'text-allow-overlap': true,
                        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
                        "text-size": 11,
                        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
                        "text-anchor": "top"

                    },
                    "paint": {
                        "text-color": "#2ab27b"
                    }
                });
```

And already tried to set "text-allow-overlap" to true. But that is not working.

Is there any chance to solve that with the layer type "symbol" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You just need to use `icon-allow-overlap: true`.

Documentation [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#layout-symbol-icon-allow-overlap).

Comment: This does not work for me. The layer should be visible from zoom level 14 to 0 but then between 10 and 7 it's gone, only to reappear when zooming in further.

Comment: @MrSnowflake did you find a solution?

Comment: You may also want to use `text-optional` to allow the marker to show up even if there isn't room for the text.